# Updating a component when props update from a function

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-props, react-component

I'm having some issues getting a component to update once I change its props.

I have a Form component and I want it to send some data to a Display Box component. The idea is that the Box will update and add new tasks each time a form is submitted.

I'm using hooks for this. So far, I have a handleInput() that returns the Display component and passes the object via props. However, I'm not seeing the results in the Display component, even though I've added a useEffect to refresh each time the props update. The console.log() from the Display component only runs once when I refresh the page, but nothing else happens when I send a new form.

Here's the Form:

```
function handleInput(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    const submittedTask = {
        name: taskName,
        category: category,
        time: estimatedTime,
        deadline: deadline
    };
    return <DisplayTasks task={submittedTask}/>
}
```

And here's the component that's not rerendering:

```
const DisplayContainer = ({ task }) => {
    const [ availableTasks, setAvailableTasks ] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        if (task) { setAvailableTasks(task) };
        console.log("Current task: ", task}
    }, [task])

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the prop, task is an object, and in js objects are assigned by reference.
Do something like this.

```
function handleInput(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    const submittedTask = {
        name: taskName,
        category: category,
        time: estimatedTime,
        deadline: deadline
    };
    return <DisplayTasks task={...submittedTask}/>
}
```